# SSIS: Is there a way to deploy packages to multiple SQL Server 2005 instances

Tags: sql-server-2005, deployment, ssis

Does anyone have any advice or techniques for deploying SSIS packages to the Integration services database.

Basically I maintain a number of SSIS packages that need to get deployed to several environments (dev, test and production), there is a need to change the individual database connections as well.

I would like to automate the process of deploying them to these environments, so it can be included in a full application deployment that can be done by the server admins.

Comment: Apologies for not updaing this post, but this has dropped in priority at the moment so i've not had a chance to look into it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a method for configuring packages for different environments using a single SQL Server configuration table (assuming all environments can connect to the configuration server).

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SSIS/66426/